# Why does typescript generic inference prioritizes arguments overs assignment?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, type-inference, typescript-generics

Typescript generics inference prioritizes arguments overs assignment. Since it prioritizes arguments any param props are automatically converted into type `unknown`, even though I assigned it to a variable whose type param is set to an object interface.

```js
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  id: string;
}

interface Client {
  person: Person;
}

class FormField {  }

class FormFieldGroup<T> {
  constructor(private props: { category: string, questions: FormRelation<Required<T>> }) {}
}

type Primitives = string | number | symbol | bigint | undefined | null;

type FormRelation<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Primitives ? FormField : FormFieldGroup<T[K]>;
}

abstract class CRUDComponent<D> {
  public abstract clientQuestions: FormRelation<D>
}

class ClientComponent extends CRUDComponent<Client> {
  public clientQuestions: FormRelation<Client> = {
    person: new FormFieldGroup({
      category: "Client",
      questions: {
        name: new FormField(),
        age: new FormField(),
        id: new FormField(),
      }
    })
  }
}

VScode: Cannot assign FormQuestionGroup<{name: unknown, age: unknown, id: unknown}> to FormQuestionGroup<Person>.
```

In Java, the diamond operator automatically infers the type to match the assignment type params. However, Typescript doesn't include the diamond operator for readability's sake. I'm using typescript 3.7 and just wondering if there a workaround to this bug, other than specifying the type.

Also when I set the props to an empty object the compiler is able to infer the Generic to the correct interface.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=38&ssc=2&pln=27&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3EcnA1SQK5kBG0LYsAAm1WvRDMCAXwIFQkWIhQBhADbAI4fKwAOmHNXRRsIFrIII1cDBmQAxLFDL3Na4fmIWrNu4+euEO4A4lBYXLoAPAAqAHw6xAg44lwIYE4AFLr0AG5wkMjZWLoY1HjICPkQDE4AnmJ0jAA0yACOXBC0wMnU-mQASkH53SCRg+3AUBDCMbHx0gCU+LIWYLX6aPRkwGDAOZ3IALw0jZLIAD7cfNAXNLV8WGq3vMAMCrdcIMIQMKDTtyAuGo1CwCGsNn1BtZdjhZkcEsgANoAaWQoGQAGsILUsDBkNEALrUaIognICAAD0gXzsqC2Oz2BwA-A4nC43B5emzAiEwhEYqTYuY5HBeOJEGAKtZbMgVP0AKoAERUWDIuhwWjAkUV8UIxF0XF4GgQbDFdAlUs04AAih0uj1Wc4ocNYTqZHIfDL1FawCq1RrtJTqcI7HKlX71SBNZFvZrdXpDcbLZrbZ0YSBSo6BkN0zGNHH4XriIUDCBqFGAO5ZnnCULhXQZIvFipVGpQerIABEsfAnaarGb7TTI0zTebJHInEr1Y5GQW-fHxfYU4gVb6NbnC8XaNEJFXM6Cwk3A+Lsmbi1YKyAA)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't make out what the question is, perhaps someone who knows TypeScript better can. The code doesn't show any error, can you say as clearly as possible what result you're seeing from it that you don't want, and what you want instead? Your `FormRelation` type only uses the **keys** from `T`, not the types of the properties they key (you're using `FormField` instead), which is why it doesn't show an error, but...

Comment: (I can say that I'd use `const group = new FormQuestionGroup<Client>(/*...*/);` instead, but it doesn't really change anything.)

Comment: I want the compiler to automatically infer the class generic type based off its assignment, so I don't have to import the interface multiple times. I don't get why typescript specification would use the type of the constructor arguments rather than the assignment generic type.

Comment: No, it's not "supposed" to be the other way around. TypeScript != Java. :-) Java's way of doing things is one way, TypeScript does things a different way. I don't see how importing has anything to do with this? (And certainly you don't have to `import` an interface multiple times.) Do you mean having to repeat it in the `const group =` line? As I've pointed out before, you don't: `const group = new FormQuestionGroup<Client>(/*...*/);`

Comment: I'm trying to create a form framework. Basically the framework should automatically generates form questions based off the supplies type. `const example: FormRelation<Client> = { name: new FormField(params), age: new FormField(params) }`

Comment: Why would I have to import interface if I can just supply it into a class that generates the form questions for me? Isn't that anti-DRY.

Comment: Nothing in the code you've shown imports anything, I think you have the wrong word there. What, specifically, is wrong with `const group = new FormQuestionGroup<Client>(/*...*/);`? That's how you do this in TypeScript AFAIK, and AFAIK there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to wrap the type with `type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never]` in order to disable argument inferance.